# How To Create An Android App To Cycle Through Backgrgound Images On Home Screen?

Tags: android, background, live-wallpaper

I need a little bit of help and I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction. I want to do something that I thought would be simple.

**Keep in mind that I'm new to Android development so this answer may seem clear and apparent to some.**

I want to create a slideshow of my images that people can download from the app store. The images should change every few seconds and the images will be installed on the home screen. I know how to create animations and I know how to create an application that displays images that change after a few seconds. **However, I do not know how to set this up so that it can be displayed on the home page!**

What I have right now is an app whose icon you have to click on to launch it. How can I modify my app so that the user could install it and have the slideshow display in the background of the home screen?

I have looked all over and I find examples of Live Wallpapers, but my images are all static. I would REALLY appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction or offer the location of a tutorial I can read through.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You want a live wallpaper: see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidLiveWallpaper.aspx for a guide.

Comment: Thank you Femi! I saw that example. However, I'm looking for examples or guidance with static images. I'm not sure about how to make my slideshow play on the home screen. Do you know of any examples that show such a thing without Live Wallpaper?

Comment: Haven't actually built a slide show, but http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/11/23/animated-slideshow-on-android/ seems like it would do what you want. You'd need to layer that into the live wallpaper implementation, but it shouldn't be too messy to do.

Comment: Thanks again Femi! I saw that one too. I have the implementation working to display and cycle through the images. I just don't know how to set it so that it displays as the background on the home page. I just can't seem to find any documentation on exactly how to set up my slideshow of images to display on the home screen. I see apps that do this in the app store so I know I'm missing something. Maybe I need to change the app and make it Live Wallpaper. The only issue is that I don't know how to use static images with animations instead of drawing things when creating the Live Wallpaper.

Comment: Oh. If you look at (for instance) http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/CubeLiveWallpaper/src/com/example/android/livecubes/cube2/CubeWallpaper2.html you will see (in the `drawFrame` method) that the live wallpaper gives you access to a surface. You can get the Canvas using `holder.lockCanvas()`, and you can then call `View.draw(canvas);` using the actual View object you are using to render your images.